# Allow discussion regarding deletion of a topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Currently, there is nowhere in the review to add a comment to discuss the deletion of a topic. Since deletion effectively hides the documentation from most views, we want as much feedback from the community as possible before voting. Therefore, I would like to request the addition of a comment thread for this case.

Comment: I agree, I think a comment thread for proposed topic deletions is necessary. I also think that the deletion of a topic should require more votes than it currently needs to be approved.